# Raspberry Pi VNC no action from keyboard or mouse

Tags: keyboard, vnc, mouse

I bought new Raspberry-pi model B with noobs OS .After configuring it, and login through PUTTY .I tried to log in through VNC.I done all supposed configuration till I managed to log through raspberry pi desktop.However I can not use any action using mouse or keyboard . just desktop showing up.Also I enabled input in VNC software . Any one experienced same problem or have an idea what is going on ?

Comment: Which VNC client are you using? Could it be due to you not capturing the mouse/keyboard on your desktop?

Comment: I'm using tight vnc

Comment: I did use many vnc servers later and followed all instructions without any results

Comment: Have you tried to start the vncserver like this: `pi@raspberrypi$                 vncserver :1

        Output:
        New 'X' desktop is raspberrypi:1

        Starting applications specified in /home/pi/.vnc/xstartup
        Log file is /home/pi/.vnc/raspberrypi:1.log`

I use TIghtvnc to view the pi, and connect to the ip like this:

`192.168.0.100:1`

Answer (score 3):

I just found the answer to MY problem, and thought I should share.  I am using the RealVnc that came pre-loaded on Jessie, and had the same issue. When starting the realVNC program, before connecting to the Raspberry Pi that it detects, right-click on the connection, select "properties" and go to OPTIONS tab. The top section is "Picture quality" and a small check box that says View-Only.  Mine was selected. My remote mouse and keyboard did not control the PI. I de-selected this "view-only" box and now it all works great. (makes sense afterwards)...

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial may answer your question, since I think you want control of display :0: http://log.liminastudio.com/writing/tutorials/remote-desktop-control-of-a-raspberry-pi